# vue switching tabs can't show the same EChart form on the second one (fixed)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
data () {
    return {
     mocktab1: mocktab1.monthData,
     mocktab2: mocktab2.monthData,
      yearTable: mock.DataFactor.yearTable,
      nowdata:"",
      nowdata1:"",
      nowdataA:"",
      nowdata1A:"",
      startTime:"",
      endTime:"",
      dataArr:[],
      dis1:false,
      dis2:false,
      }

initAlpha(next){
        Indicator.open("Loading ")
        this.$axios({
          method:"GET",
          //Get first substation id
          url:"/api/app/DataAnalysis/getSubstation",
        }).then((res)=>{
          this.$axios({
            method:"GET",
            url:"/api/app/index/getSubstation"
          }).then((res)=>{
            console.log(res,"now")
          })
          // if(!next){
          //   this.firstId = res.data[0].substation.looplist[0].id
          // }
          this.$axios({
            method:"GET",
            url:"/api/app/EnergyAnalysis/intoLineRecordyear?intolineId=" + this.firstId + "&appStartTime=" + this.startTime
          }).then((res)=>{
            console.log(res)
            let data = res.data
            this.dataArr = res.data
            let arr = []
            data.forEach((item)=>{
              arr.push(item.pf)
            })
            if(arr.length == 0){
              this.dis1 = true
            }else{
              this.dis1 = false
              setTimeout(()=>{
                let eCharts = echarts.init(document.getElementById('enEchar'));
                eCharts.clear()
                eCharts.setOption(this.optionsthree(arr))
              },0)
             
            }
             Indicator.close()
          })
          }).catch((err)=>{
             toast("error")
              Indicator.close()
          })
      },
      openPicker() {
        this.$refs.picker.open();
      },
      handleConfirm(value){
        let mytime = changeTime(value)
        this.startTime = mytime.slice(0,4)
        this.nowdata = mytime.slice(0,4)
        this.nowdata1 = mytime.slice(0,4)
        this.endTime = this.nowdata + "-12-31 " + "23:59:59"
        this.initThree("next")
        console.log(this.startTime)
        console.log(this.endTime)
        console.log(this.firstId)
      },
      // energy-echars
      optionsthree(data){
          let option = {
            tooltip: {
                trigger: 'axis',
                axisPointer: {
                    lineStyle: {
                        color: '#57617B'
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                icon: 'circle',
                itemWidth: 8,
                itemHeight: 8,
                itemGap: 13,
                data: ['Data1', 'Data2'],
                right: '2%',
                textStyle: {
                    fontSize: 12,
                    color: '#fff',
                },
                top:'2%'
            },
            grid: {
              left: '12%',
              top: '20%',
              right: '1%',
              bottom: '18%',
            },
            xAxis: {
              type: 'category',
              boundaryGap: false,
              data: ['Jan',"Feb", 'Mar',"Apr",'May',"Jun",'Jul',"Aug",'Sep',"Oct",'Nov',"Dec"],
              axisLine: {
                lineStyle: {      
                  color: '#68707A',
                  width: 1,
                  type: 'solid'
                },
              },
              axisTick: {
                show: false
              },
              axisLabel: {
                color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)'
              }
            },
            yAxis: {
              type: 'value',
              max:0.95,
              nameTextStyle: {
                color: '#ffffff',
                align: 'left',
                padding: [0, 13, 0, 0]
              },
              splitLine: {
                lineStyle: {
                    color: '#68707A'
                }
              },
              axisLine: {
                lineStyle: {    
                  color: '#68707A',
                  width: 1,
                  type: 'solid'
                },
              },
              axisTick: {
                show: false
              },
              axisLabel: {
                interval: 0 ,
                color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)'
              }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Data',
                type: 'line',
                smooth: true,
                symbol: 'circle',
                symbolSize: 5,
                showSymbol: false,
                lineStyle: {
                    normal: {
                        width: 2
                    },
                },
                itemStyle: {
                    normal: {
                        color: '#00BEDB',
                    }
                },
                data: data
            },{
                name: 'Contents',
                type: 'line',
                smooth: true,
                symbol: 'circle',
                symbolSize: 5,
                showSymbol: false,
                lineStyle: {               
                    normal: {
                        width: 2
                    }
                },
                itemStyle: {
                    normal: {
                        color: '#00BEDB',
                    }
                },
                data: ["0.95","0.95","0.95"]
            }]
        };
        return option
        },
 
 initBravo(next){
        Indicator.open("Loading ")
        this.$axios({
          method:"GET",
          //Get first substation id
          url:"/api/app/DataAnalysis/getSubstation",
        }).then((res)=>{
          this.$axios({
            method:"GET",
            url:"/api/app/index/getSubstation"
          }).then((res)=>{
            console.log(res,"now")
          })
          // if(!next){
          //   this.firstId = res.data[0].substation.looplist[0].id
          // }
          this.$axios({
            method:"GET",
            url:"/api/app/EnergyAnalysis/intoLineRecordyear?intolineId=" + this.firstId + "&appStartTime=" + this.startTime
          }).then((res)=>{
            console.log(res)
            let data = res.data
            this.dataArr = res.data
            let arr = []
            data.forEach((item)=>{
              arr.push(item.pf)
            })
            if(arr.length == 0){
              this.dis2 = true
            }else{
              this.dis2 = false
              setTimeout(()=>{
                let eCharts = echarts.init(document.getElementById('enEchar'));
                eCharts.clear()
                eCharts.setOption(this.optionsthree(arr))
              },0)
             
            }
             Indicator.close()
          })
          }).catch((err)=>{
             toast("error")
              Indicator.close()
          })
      },
      openPicker() {
        this.$refs.picker.open();
      },
      handleConfirm(value){
        let mytime = changeTime(value)
        this.startTime = mytime.slice(0,4)
        this.nowdataA = mytime.slice(0,4)
        this.nowdata1A = mytime.slice(0,4)
        this.endTime = this.nowdata + "-12-31 " + "23:59:59"
        this.initThree("next")
        console.log(this.startTime)
        console.log(this.endTime)
        console.log(this.firstId)
      },
      // energy-echars
      optionsthree(data){
          let option = {
            tooltip: {
                trigger: 'axis',
                axisPointer: {
                    lineStyle: {
                        color: '#57617B'
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                icon: 'circle',
                itemWidth: 8,
                itemHeight: 8,
                itemGap: 13,
                data: ['Data1', 'Data2'],
                right: '2%',
                textStyle: {
                    fontSize: 12,
                    color: '#fff',
                },
                top:'2%'
            },
            grid: {
              left: '12%',
              top: '20%',
              right: '1%',
              bottom: '18%',
            },
            xAxis: {
              type: 'category',
              boundaryGap: false,
              data: ['Jan',"Feb", 'Mar',"Apr",'May',"Jun",'Jul',"Aug",'Sep',"Oct",'Nov',"Dec"],
              axisLine: {
                lineStyle: {      
                  color: '#68707A',
                  width: 1,
                  type: 'solid'
                },
              },
              axisTick: {
                show: false
              },
              axisLabel: {
                color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)'
              }
            },
            yAxis: {
              type: 'value',
              max:0.95,
              nameTextStyle: {
                color: '#ffffff',
                align: 'left',
                padding: [0, 13, 0, 0]
              },
              splitLine: {
                lineStyle: {
                    color: '#68707A'
                }
              },
              axisLine: {
                lineStyle: {    
                  color: '#68707A',
                  width: 1,
                  type: 'solid'
                },
              },
              axisTick: {
                show: false
              },
              axisLabel: {
                interval: 0 ,
                color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)'
              }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Data',
                type: 'line',
                smooth: true,
                symbol: 'circle',
                symbolSize: 5,
                showSymbol: false,
                lineStyle: {
                    normal: {
                        width: 2
                    },
                },
                itemStyle: {
                    normal: {
                        color: '#00BEDB',
                    }
                },
                data: data
            },{
                name: 'Contents',
                type: 'line',
                smooth: true,
                symbol: 'circle',
                symbolSize: 5,
                showSymbol: false,
                lineStyle: {               
                    normal: {
                        width: 2
                    }
                },
                itemStyle: {
                    normal: {
                        color: '#00BEDB',
                    }
                },
                data: ["0.95","0.95","0.95"]
            }]
        };
        return option
        },
```

Apologize, last Saturday I have only sent screenshots of the interface. Here I add my full Vue script, the problem is still as the previous one. As the second page is correctly showing the EChart with data and X and Y axes, but when I copy the same code to the third page, the EChart won't show anything.
In order to make the script short, I deleted the code of the first and third page, also the mounted head{} and methods{}. The script of the third page is the same as the second, only changed the startInitLoad(next) into initThree(next). Thanks to everyone who replied to my previous post yesterday.

```html
<div id="Tab1">
          <div class="enHeadText">Form1</div>

          <div class="enCardBox">
            <div class="enCardHead">
              <div class="enSelectYear" @click="openPicker">{{nowdata1}}year<div class="enSelectBtn"></div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="enEchars">
              <div v-if="dis1">
                <p class="nodata" >No Data</p>
                <img class="noimg"  src="../../../../static/img/noDate@2x.png">
              </div>
              <div id="enEchar" v-else></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="entab">
                  <div class="head">
                      <div>Data1</div>
                      <div>Data2</div>
                      <div>Data3</div>
                      <div>Data4</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="scroll">
                    <div class="entable">
                      <div class="content" v-for="(item,index) in dataArr">
                        <div>{{item.createTime.slice(0,7)}}</div>
                        <div>{{item.p}}</div>
                        <div>{{item.q}}</div>
                        <div>{{item.pf}}</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
              </div>
              <mt-datetime-picker
                  ref="picker"
                  type="date"
                  v-model="nowdata"
                  year-format="{value} year"
                  @confirm="handleConfirm"
                  :visible-item-count="5" 
                >
              </mt-datetime-picker>

        </div>

    <div id="Tab2">
          <div class="enHeadText">Form1</div>

          <div class="enCardBox">
            <div class="enCardHead">
              <div class="enSelectYear" @click="openPicker">{{nowdata1}}year<div class="enSelectBtn"></div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="enEchars">
              <div v-if="dis2">
                <p class="nodata" >No Data</p>
                <img class="noimg"  src="../../../../static/img/noDate@2x.png">
              </div>
              <div id="enEchar" v-else></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="entab">
                  <div class="head">
                      <div>Data1</div>
                      <div>Data2</div>
                      <div>Data3</div>
                      <div>Data4</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="scroll">
                    <div class="entable">
                      <div class="content" v-for="(item,index) in dataArr">
                        <div>{{item.createTime.slice(0,7)}}</div>
                        <div>{{item.p}}</div>
                        <div>{{item.q}}</div>
                        <div>{{item.pf}}</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
              </div>
              <mt-datetime-picker
                  ref="picker"
                  type="date"
                  v-model="nowdata"
                  year-format="{value} year"
                  @confirm="handleConfirm"
                  :visible-item-count="5" 
                >
              </mt-datetime-picker>

        </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vue switching tabs can't show the same EChart form on the second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62483855/vue-switching-tabs-cant-show-the-same-echart-form-on-the-second-one)

Comment: this is my previous question

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. Instead edit the original to add more detail. Also, you seem to have added more information to this question as "answers" instead of editing the original. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @LiHanXu Also, please avoid deleting questions once they have been solved. The point of this site is that questions are useful not only for the people who ask them but for future users with a similar problem. For the same reason, anything posted as an answer should fully answer the question instead of adding details to it. As the question's owner, you can [edit] your question instead.